# New instance without spawning a new process

Tags: windows, multithreading, process

I have noticed that some applications like firefox/iexplorer/windows image viewer etc are not creating new processes for new instances of the application. To explain what i mean i would expect that when opening two instances of firefox for example there would exist two different processes. Some other applications i tested had a process per instance.

My first question is why would someone use the one process multiple instances model? It seems a lot more complex to me than having an instance per process. I suppose that one reason may be resources usage.

My second question is how would you implement something like this? Assigning some threads to the new instance for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, one process for multiple "instances" keeps all the processes memory in one place, removing the need to use IPC to send messages between different "instances".

To implement something like this you can use the CreateMutex API here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

If the mutex already exists and another instance of your app is launched, you can just forward the app open call to the existing instance of the app.